# image map, image should change onhover,

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, imagemap

Why is the image not changing on hover? The image should change on hover and onclick and use the same image map

```js
<script>
function changeImage() {

document.getElementById('image').src = document.getElementById('some_id').getAttribute('data-img-src'); 
};

</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <img id="image" src="http://imgur.com/SY5h8EC" map="#map" />
<map name="map">
<map id="some_id" data-img-src='http://imgur.com/Sch9YFq'>
<area shape="poly" coords="172,227,181,224,183,213,189,201,195,193,199,190,199,184,126,93,135,93,123,79,103,96,84,117,68,140,58,162,51,186,48,201,47,214,135,219,130,227,148,227,147,225,151,227,149,223,153,227,153,221,156,225,157,214,160,202,166,190,174,179,176,177,174,174,191,176,192,192,189,189,180,200,174,212,172,224,172,227" width="453" height="453" id="area1"
              onmouseover=" changeImage();"/>
</map>
     </map> 
 
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: For one thing, your script is invalid. You don't have the `function` keyword in your function declaration, though you seem to not be calling that function anyway. Another is that `some-id` is not a valid identifier. You can use `document.getElementById("some-id")`.

Comment: thank you. I have made the changes . still it is not working

Comment: @Mitali can you post the updated code? Also where is the javascript stored? In another file?

Comment: I have updated the code. the javascript is storedin same file after body tag

Comment: @Mitali where is the JavaScript stored? Is it in another file? Why do you have a `<map>` inside another `<map>`? I don't see the change @squint suggested in your update.

Comment: You have to apply the change from some_id to document.getElementById("some_id") aswell as any other id you're using on the script.
Also, do you have any CSS? because I can't understand what you trying to do yet

Comment: I want to set up map on image. when a person cliks on particular area another image(which is same but has color change showing that part is selected should come) and use the same map. So i am using map in another map for map id.

Comment: there is no css. This is the full code. I have done the changes. Is it right now?

Comment: You can't do this:

    document.getElementById('image.src')

instead you have to do:

    document.getElementById("image").src

Comment: @Belakorr thank you. did the change still not working

Comment: @Mitali Where is your javascript stored? Is it in a different file from the HTML? Is it in the same file?

Comment: @stackErr it is in the same file

Comment: I have a image on which when mouseover diffrent part diffrent image hould show up and mouse out the original image should return. Now on mouse clik the cliked image should be set as base image and use the same image map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the image links and wrote the code into a jsFiddle, you also had to change "map" to "usemap" and I got rid of one of the maps, I dont think you need it:

```
<body>
  <img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/SY5h8EC.png" usemap="#map" />
    <map name="map" id="some_id" data-img-src='http://i.imgur.com/Sch9YFq.png'>
      <area shape="poly" coords="172,227,181,224,183,213,189,201,195,193,199,190,199,184,126,93,135,93,123,79,103,96,84,117,68,140,58,162,51,186,48,201,47,214,135,219,130,227,148,227,147,225,151,227,149,223,153,227,153,221,156,225,157,214,160,202,166,190,174,179,176,177,174,174,191,176,192,192,189,189,180,200,174,212,172,224,172,227" id="area1" onmouseover=" changeImage();" />
    </map>
</body>
<script>
function changeImage() { document.getElementById('image').src=document.getElementById('some_id').getAttribute('data-img-src');
}
</script>
```

Working Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3eqb4uuj/

If you need help with something else please comment and I'll edit it

Comment: Thank you, I will go through it and check

Comment: This works just great. :) I want original image on mouseout. How to do that? Is there a way to store the value of original image id before changing it by mouseover?

Comment: create another function, and use onmouseout instead, and change the image again when you move the mouse out, that should do the trick!

Something like:
`<area onmouseout="mouseout()"`

Comment: Also i have various parts of the image which change on area shape co ordinates. So if the id is same for all of them .it wont help

Comment: I see your point, in order to make that you will have to either create a function to every part of the image you want to change, or give it a different id to each area and call the same function with the id as a parameter

Comment: @mitali remember to tick the answer as correct since I fixed the initial question, thanks!

Comment: <script>
function changeImage() {  
var temp=getElementById(id);
document.getElementById('image').src=temp.getAttribute('data-img-src');
}

</script>

Comment: onmouseover=" changeImage(this.id); is this right method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104471/discussion-between-belakorr-and-mitali).